# Formula over multiple sheets with condition

Tags: excel

I have five sheets named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, ..., `Sheet5`. I want to sum up the values from cell `A2` to cell `A10` over all these sheets. But I only want to include a sheet in this sum if its value in cell `A1` is equal to `3`. What is the formula I require to achieve this?

Comment: `IF(sheet1!a1=3;SUM(sheet1!a1:a10);0)` and just `+` for every sheet (change sheet1 to [sheetname]). It does: get the sum of the sheet if a1 is 3 else add zero

Comment: Are any of the values in those ranges potentially negative?

Comment: No, they are all positive.

Answer (score 2):

This code should be the end all be all on your question.

It checks each sheet and adds all the numbers (from A2 to A10) from the sheets inwhich A1 = 3 and excludes the sheets that does not meet the requirement.

I tested it.

`=SUM(IF(sheet1!A1=3, SUM(sheet1!A2:A10), 0),IF(sheet2!A1=3, SUM(sheet2!A2:A10), 0),IF(sheet3!A1=3, SUM(sheet3!A2:A10), 0),IF(sheet4!A1=3, SUM(sheet4!A2:A10), 0),IF(sheet1!A5=3, SUM(sheet5!A2:A10), 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(N(INDIRECT("'Sheet"&{1,2,3,4,5}&"'!A1"))=3,SUMIF(INDIRECT("'Sheet"&{1,2,3,4,5}&"'!A2:A10"),">0")))
```

Regards